# Elasticsearch node js point in time search_phase_execution_exception

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, point-in-time

```
    const body = {
  query: {
    geo_shape: {
      geometry: {
        relation: 'within',
        shape: {
          type: 'polygon',
          coordinates: [$polygon],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  pit: {
    id:  "t_yxAwEPZXNyaS1wYzYtMjAxN3IxFjZxU2RBTzNyUXhTUV9XbzhHSk9IZ3cAFjhlclRmRGFLUU5TVHZKNXZReUc3SWcAAAAAAAALmpMWQkNwYmVSeGVRaHU2aDFZZExFRjZXZwEWNnFTZEFPM3JReFNRX1dvOEdKT0hndwAA",
    keep_alive: "1m",
  },
};
```

Query fails with search_phase_execution_exception at onBody
Without pit query works fine but it's needed to retrieve more than 10000 hits

Answer (score 3):

Well, using PIT in NodeJS ElasticSearch's client is not clear, or at least is not well documented. You can create a PIT using the client like:

```
const pitRes = await elastic.openPointInTime({
  index: index,
  keep_alive: "1m"
});

pit_id = pitRes.body.id;
```

But there is no way to use that pit_id in the search method, and it's not documented properly :S

BUT, you can use the scroll API as follows:

```
const scrollSearch =  await elastic.helpers.scrollSearch({
index: index,
body: {
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [ "vm_ref", "org", "vm" ],
      "query": organization + moreQuery
    },
  "sort": [
    { "utc_date": "desc" }
  ]
  }
}});
```

And then read the results as follows:

```
let res = [];

try {
  for await (const result of scrollSearch) {
    res.push(...result.body.hits.hits);
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

I know that's not the exact answer to your question, but I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Honestly, sometimes it's better to attack the Elastic's API directly instead of using the Node client. The API is better documented and is not limited to the implementation of the client. In fact, it's pretty simple, so I suggest you to use the API directly ;)

Comment: This works ok, but using `size` > 10000 will result to a `ResponseError: search_phase_execution_exception` error.

Comment: Fair enough! Better to use a small number there ;)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of point-in-time for pagination of search results is now documented in ElasticSearch.  You can find more or less detailed explanations here: [Paginate search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)

I prepared an example that may give an idea about how to implement the workflow, described in the documentation:

```
async function searchWithPointInTime(cluster, index, chunkSize, keepAlive) {
    if (!chunkSize) {
        chunkSize = 5000;
    }
    if (!keepAlive) {
        keepAlive = "1m";
    }

    const client = new Client({ node: cluster });
    let pointInTimeId = null;
    let searchAfter = null;

    try {
        // Open point in time
        pointInTimeId = (await client.openPointInTime({ index, keep_alive: keepAlive })).body.id;

        // Query next chunk of data
        while (true) {
            const size = remained === null ? chunkSize : Math.min(remained, chunkSize);
            const response = await client.search({
                // Pay attention: no index here (because it will come from the point-in-time)
                body: {
                    size: chunkSize,
                    track_total_hits: false, // This will make query faster
                    query: {
                        // (1) TODO: put any filter you need here (instead of match_all)
                        match_all: {},
                    },
                    pit: {
                        id: pointInTimeId,
                        keep_alive: keepAlive,
                    },
                    // Sorting should be by _shard_doc or at least include _shard_doc
                    sort: [{ _shard_doc: "desc" }],
                    // The next parameter is very important - it tells Elastic to bring us next portion
                    ...(searchAfter !== null && { search_after: [searchAfter] }),
                },
            });

            const { hits } = response.body.hits;
            if (!hits || !hits.length) {
                break; // No more data
            }

            for (hit of hits) {
                // (2) TODO: Do whatever you need with results
            }

            // Check if we done reading the data
            if (hits.length < size) {
                break; // We finished reading all data
            }

            // Get next value for the 'search after' position 
            // by extracting the _shard_doc from the sort key of the last hit
            searchAfter = hits[hits.length - 1].sort[0];
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
    } finally {
        // Close point in time
        if (pointInTime) {
            await client.closePointInTime({ body: { id: pointInTime } });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When calling `client.openPointInTime({ index: index, keep_alive: keepAlive })` I'm getting a `ResponseError: parse_exception` and a `body: { error: [Object], status: 400 }` so I had to change it like `client.openPointInTime({ body: { index: index, keep_alive: keepAlive }})`